# Src attribute of html5 audio player

Tags: jquery, html

When I open my page it says error loading file. How do I use my html5 audio player to play this soundcloud file?

How else do I define the src attribute?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
 <script src="audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>
<body style="background-color: rgb(152, 152, 152);
 margin-left: 39% !important;
 margin-top: 22% !important;">
 <audio src="https://soundcloud.com/hardwell/coldplay-sky-full-of-stars-hardwell-remix-download" preload="auto">
</audio>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to give the URL to the actual audio file itself - *not* the page that plays it.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get that URL?

Comment: You'll need to inspect the document and look for it, or check the network traffic to find where it's being read from. You should note that SoundCloud will most likely block any access to their files from non-authorised domains. You should use their SDK directly to get access to a music stream: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming